# How can make a React Native app suggest the user credentials?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

The most similar example I can make is Paypal app. If you have more than one account it will suggest you multiple accounts and you can just click on the account and it will autocomplete the login form.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: cant understand what you want